# Can you automatically put a method's code into its DockBlock in phpDocumentor 2?

Tags: php, documentation, comments, phpdoc

I've installed [phpDocumentor 2](http://www.phpdoc.org/) and want to include the source for each method in the generated documentation. However, I notice that the inline `@source` tag does not appear to be picked up, and there only seems to be reference to it in [phpDocumentor 1's documentation](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLframesConverter/default/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.inlinesource.pkg.html).

Here's what I've been trying:

```
/**
 * Test Comment
 *
 * {@source}
 */
public function test_method() {
    echo('Hi!');
}
```

I was hoping `{@source}` would be replaced with the following HTML:

```
<code>
    echo('Hi!');
</code>
```

Is this now deprecated? And if so, is there any way to achieve this using phpDocumentor 2?

Comment: I looked into phpdoc a while back and discovered it's fairly outdated and not maintained anymore, you may want to take a google for doxygen, runs on most platform and while a little tricky to set all the options up, generates nice documentaion from your code

Comment: @Dale: Phpdocumentor 2 is current (not that doxygen ain't a good choice, too)

Comment: http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/starting.html < doxygen

Comment: Ah I haven't looked into it for years

Comment: It *looks* like it does not exist any longer: http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/index.html - however, you might want to review the source and as well file a feature request to get support for it.

Comment: I've just noticed a `--sourcecode` switch with the description: "Whether to include syntax highlighted source code". Including it doesn't seem to do anything though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a proper look into this today and spoken with Mike van Riel on the phpDocumentor mailing list.

Simply put - you can't do exactly what I'm after.

PHPDocumentor 2's default template, 'responsive', has no support for dynamically showing code. What you can do is switch to an alternate template, 'new-black', and that will show you the source code for the corresponding file. This works with the `@filesource` tag and there's a `--sourcecode` switch when building the documentation which will automatically enable this for all files.

However, what you *can't* do is include code at method level, which is what the `@source` tag is for. That simply isn't supported, and the raw `structure.xml` file doesn't even store this information.

Having said that, Mike has said "I definitely want the functionality" - so here's to hoping it gets included in the future! I haven't got time this second, but I'll submit it as an issue on GitHub. If you're keen on having this functionality too, please [make it known](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues).